# Using aceoledb without instaling it on computer

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

I tried to write data to the `.accdb` file without `MS Access` installed, only with `ACE.OLEDB` and it works fine. 
Is it now possible to add a provider like `ACE.OLEDB 12.0` to the project, so that it doesn't have to be installed on the computer. I tried to add `dll` to to resources/references but it would be to easy.
I'm using C# and .Net 3.5